# How to view saved passwords in ODOO?

Tags: postgresql, odoo

I am working in ODOO 10. But I need to know that how to view the saved passwords without updating or changing them. If I check through the database(PostgreSQL),the password's field value is empty as it gets value from a wizard.

Answer (score 6):

No You can't see the saved passwords , it will store as encrypted form in the database.There is no option to get the passwords.

Answer (score 1):

In odoo 10 password field is encrypted. You need to decrypt that externally using different techniques of encryption in python.